# View Bugs on Sprint Tracking Board

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-boards, sprint

When branching off of the basic process, task items display on the sprint board. However bug items (and their child tasks) do not show their parent bug. See Below:

[image: Unparented category]

Tasks should show their parent. In fact, if I edit a bug from the board, I can see it on the board. See below:

[image: Parent shown in Task Board]

Unfortunately, after refreshing hte page, the item returns to the unparented category.

TL;DR - How can I configure my sprint board to display task parent items rather than only features?

edit: Gear image [image: settings menu]

Comment: What are your Settings for "Working with Bugs" if you click the Gear icon for the Sprints or Boards view?

Comment: @MichaelMurray, that option is not available for me. I've edited the original post with a view of my gear icon menu.

Comment: Thanks! I'm double checking, but this might be a limitation of the Basic Process. You might need to use a fork of Agile or Scrum to manage Bugs as you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Basic Process does not have a Bug type out of the box, the Board/Sprint views do not support customizing those types at all. Since you make a fork of a basic process, you're missing that configuration option as well.

To manage bugs as you are describing you would need to switch the project to one of the out of the box Processes that support Bugs as a type or create a fork of one of those processes.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. We'll probably have to do that. Any idea why it works temporarily as is?

Comment: Honestly, it seems like a display glitch on the view. Likely because it's a type the Basic Process board doesn't know how to handle. I was able to replicate the behavior in my sandbox org, but can't see why it moves from the unparented grouping when you edit.

Comment: Cool! Thank you again. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @MichaelMurry if we switch the process, do we lose existing items or are they mapped somehow?

Comment: NVM, I found a knowledge article on it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-basic-to-agile?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

> View Bugs on Sprint Tracking Board

The reason for this issue is that your basic process limits the bug workitem type.

When you check the Backlog levels of the basic process：

[image]

Obviously, the custom Bug work items appear on the requirement backlog or the iteration backlog **based on the team's setting**. However, there is no such team's setting about it for the basic process.

[image]

**To resolve this issue**, we need to change the basic process to other process which  track bugs on the Backlog, like: `Agile`, `Scrum`.

You could check all the process on this document:

[Basic, Agile, Scrum, and CMMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process#basic-agile-scrum-and-cmmi)

[image]

After change the basic process to other process, we just need select the Bugs are managed with tasks on the settings:

[image]